# Retrieving more than 100.000 records using select statement

Tags: soql, performance

I have a custom object called equipment___c with more than 100.000 records, and also related to product object. 
To get product codes that are in equipment object, i used the following query:

```
select product.productCode from Equipment__c
```

Here i'm getting 100000 records as a result.(checked this from dataloader).
one productcode can be assigned to multiple equipments...
So when i ran this query there will be repeated product codes.
But i want distinct product codes.. so that i can display those codes in VF page.

when i'm using the above SOQL query in controller, i'm the getting the following error:

```
Too many rows 50001.
```

I also checked the following query:

```
select count_distinct(product.productcode) from equipment__c
```

I got the count as 689.
so i want to print these 689 product codes in vf page.

I also tried GROUP BY clause. but it throws an error

```
Aggregate query does not support querymore(), use LIMIT to restrict the results to a single batch.
```

please help, how can i get distinct product codes..

Comment: If you're not gonna do any DML (and some other things) you can use the readonly attribute: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_classes_annotation_ReadOnly.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_classes_annotation_ReadOnly.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Comment: Unfortunately im using DML operations in my controller @Lex

Comment: Can you elaborate on your data model and the information you're trying to query ? (by updating the question) Doing such queries sort of indicate you either have not optimized your data model, or you're trying to implement things in a non-optimal way.

Answer (score 1):

Use a  semi-join, e.g.

> select productCode from productCodes where id in (select product from
>   equipment__c)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is only one solution.

Use readonly attribute in your VF page (page1)and fetch all productCode:

```
select product.productCode from Equipment__c
```

Then loop through all records and create list of unique productCode.

Then pass these productCode to next page(Page2) if user want to perform and DML  operation.

On this (page2) you can skip readonly tag and perform DML operation and you already have list of unique productCode from page1.

If user do not want to perform any DML operation then he can view all productCode on page1 itself.

Note that if productCode size is very large like 100k or so then you may face governor limit related to heap size.

Otherwise it should just work fine for 689 records.

Answer (score -2):

When you need to show more than 1000 record on VF page or want to process on more then 50000 records, you must use AJAX toolkit of salesforce.

include connection.js into your page like below

```
<script src="/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now use following code snippet to understand and apply as your requirement

```
var result = sforce.connection.query("select name, id from account");
var queryMore = true;
while (queryMore) {
var records = result.getArray("records");
for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
//process records[i]
}
if (result.getBoolean("done")) {
queryMore = false;
} else {
result = sforce.connection.queryMore(result.queryLocator);
}
}
```

Please use this and let me know if you need any help.

Please mark this as an answer if this solve your problem :)

Comment: Getting huge data volumes asychronosly to the browser isn't really a solution. There' s gonna be a limit at which your browser runs out of memory.

Comment: In above example we are explicitly calling querymore request for subsequent 2000 records. 
So at a time you will get 2000 records in your browser memory which is not too much.
You can remove while loop and can call after processing on first 2000 records for more records and can destroy previous records.
This way will not going to full your browser memory. :)

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Can you please tell me why people are down voting my answer ? :)

I am feeling so demotivated :)

Comment: I can't tell you why others are downvoting, but I downvoted because I think it's not a solution. As explained in my previous comment. Technically it may be a workaround, but that doesn't make it a realistic solution.

Comment: If this is not a solution then can you please tell what is the solution for retrieving more then 100000 records as this is the question ?
I really want to know the realistic solution ??

Comment: sales_lion, Why solution is not realistic? Because information is processed via a browser, AJAX works best with small amounts of data, max 200 records. Ajax uses soap API, it takes time to process in construct/deconstruct of data received. Browser are inefficient in processing large amount of data (inefficient memory management). Your solution gives inappropriate use of toolkit which would require too much processing time, and browser rendering will be too slow. These may be the reason of downvotings. Pls consider help users, don't get demotivated just by voting only. @SamuelDeRycke is right.

Comment: Can anyone provide me realistic solution ??

In salesforce we don't have many things available and we do some workaround for that and that's what I provide as a solution .